# amCharts 4 (v4) Set specific colors in pie chart

Tags: graph, amcharts, beta

I am testing this framework Amcharts and i get to configure specific colors in amcharts v3 like this:

```
pieChart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
      "type": "pie",
      "colors": ["#388E3C", "#FBC02D", "#0288d1", "#F44336", "#8E24AA"],
      -- other stuff
    });
```

But i am finding hard to make the same in Amcharts V4... i tried things like this

```
pieSeries.colors._list = am4core.color['#388E3C', '#FBC02D', '#0288D1', '#F44336', '#8E24AA']

pieSeries.slices.template.fill = am4core.color('#388E3C', '#FBC02D', '#0288D1', '#F44336', '#8E24AA')
```

or this

```
"series": [{
    "type": "PieSeries3D",
    "colors": ["#388E3C", "#FBC02D", "#0288d1", "#F44336", "#8E24AA"],
}]
```

but in the end does not work... anyone adventuring here too?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`colors` is a `ColorSet` object, which is a wrapper for an array of `color` objects in AmCharts v4. You have to create an array of `color` objects, assign them to a `ColorSet` object's `list` array, then assign it to the series' `colors` property:

```
var colorSet = new am4core.ColorSet();
colorSet.list = ["#388E3C", "#FBC02D", "#0288d1", "#F44336", "#8E24AA"].map(function(color) {
  return new am4core.color(color);
});
pieSeries.colors = colorSet;
```

Comment: Thank you, i was understanding wrong how things works in V4

Answer (score 6):

You can do that:

```
pieSeries.colors.list = [
    new am4core.color('#388E3C'),
    new am4core.color('#FBC02D'),
    new am4core.color('#0288D1'),
    new am4core.color('#F44336'),
    new am4core.color('#8E24AA'),
]
```

Or like @xorspark

```
pieSeries.colors.list = ["#388E3C", "#FBC02D", "#0288d1", "#F44336", "#8E24AA"].map(function(color) {
      return new am4core.color(color);
});
```

Doc is here: https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/colors/#Manually_setting_color_sets

Answer (score 3):

I've found a slightly different way:

```
  const myColors= [
    "#0000ff",
    "#ff0000",
    "#ffff00",
    "#ff00ff"
  ];
  series.columns.template.adapter.add("fill", (fill, target) => {
    return am4core.color(myColors[target.dataItem.index]);
  });
```

At least this works with an `am4charts.ColumnSeries()` Object. The number of columns must be equal the number of colors of course.

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly on radar chart.

Comment: Worked perfectly on the pie chart also. Just change series.columns in series.slices for the ones who found this solution.

Thank you.